# How to get the File Description programmatically?

Tags: 8, entities, files

In Drupal 8, like Drupal 7, you can enable the file description in the file field setting.

But once my file entity is loaded in my preprocess, I don't know how can I get the description value entered for my file.
I've tried (without success) :

```
$myfileentity->toArray();
$myfileentity->get('description');
$myfileentity->get('description_field');
$myfileentity->label();
```

Any Idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The description is stored on the file field, not on the file entity. To access it, use `$node->yourfilefield->description`.

Comment: Cool, that's working even though it seems odd, I think there should be a function like getDescription(). Also I added a solution for multiple field which was my case.

Comment: Entity field properties don't have methods, it is always properties, which is actually powered by magic __get()/__set() and so on methods. Multi-value is then just $entity->yourfield[1]->description.

Answer (score 1):

If the field has multiple files you can get the description like so:

```
$values = $field->getValue();
foreach($values as $value){
   $descriptions[] = $value['description'];
}
```

Tested in Drupal 8.4.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of the field 'description' you can use something like this:

```
$fid = 1; //Your file id
$file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid);
$file->get('filename')->value; //here to get the file name
```

To get the list, try  `dpm(file->toArray());`

You can check this pages to know about files and fields.

- http://www.drupal8.ovh/index.php/en/tutoriels/81/handle-file-drupal-8
- http://www.drupal8.ovh/index.php/en/tutoriels/58/get-field-value-of-a-node-entity

Comment: That gives me the 'filename' like 'mypdf.pdf' where I need the description I put into the field like 'Test PDF'. I ended up making a direct query into the database to get the description stored in node__field_pdf. I'm up for a better solution.