# How to get the File Description on a custom field formatter?

Tags: theming, 8, entities, files

Greetings to all of you.

This is my first question posted around here, so any suggestions are welcome on improving how to better formulate questions.

Into the matter.
I have the following code in a Drupal 8 site:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\MyModuleFormatter.
 */

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'mymodule' formatter.
 *
 * @FieldFormatter(
 *   id = "mymodule",
 *   label = @Translation("My Module"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "file"
 *   }
 * )
 */

class MyModuleFormatter extends MyModuleFormatterBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
    $element = array();
    $files = $this->getEntitiesToView($items, $langcode);

    /**
     * Early opt-out if the field is empty.
     */
    if (empty($files)) {
      return $elements;
    }

    foreach ($files as $delta => $file) {
      $file_uri = $file->getFileUri();

      $elements[$delta] = array(
        '#theme' => 'mymodule',
        '#files' => array(Url::fromUri(file_create_url($file_uri)));
      );
    }

    return $elements;
  }
}
```

So far so good. Everything is working.

Now, I would like to include in $elements the file description.
Something like:

```
foreach ($files as $delta => $file) {
  $file_uri = $file->getFileUri();
  $file_description = <someting> // That's what is needed...

  $elements[$delta] = array(
    '#theme' => 'mymodule',
    '#files' => array(Url::fromUri(file_create_url($file_uri)));
    '#descriptions' => array($file_description);  // ...so it can go here.
  );
}
```

As stated by [Berdir](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/31/berdir), it looks that the [description is stored on the file field, not on the file entity](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215996/how-to-get-the-file-description-programmatically).
Yes, seems to be there, somewhere in $items.

How to get it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, normally you find the values from the field in $items[$delta].

To make this easier for field formatters `getEntitiesToView()` puts the item in the returned array. You find the item in `_referringItem`:

```
$item = $file->_referringItem;
$description =  $item->description;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulties doing this too. The trick is to use `getEntitiesToView()` indeed. To get the function working, the following use statement is essential:

```
use Drupal\file\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\FileFormatterBase;
```

Full code for the formatter can be found here: https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/show-file-description-custom-formatter-drupal-8